# Is every injective function invertible?

Tags: calculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

Is every injective function invertible? How could I prove such thing? (Or is it just a necessary but not sufficient condition?)

If $f:A\rightarrow B$ is injective then $f(a) = f(b) \Rightarrow a = b$ for all $a,b\in A$.

If $f(x)=y$ is invertible, there is some function $g(y)=x$.

I don't see how to put these things together, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: I find it useful to remember that "an injective function is bijective onto its image".

Comment: Some related older posts: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994282/inverse-of-a-function-exists-iff-function-is-bijective and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232674/show-that-f-is-injective-iff-there-exists-a-g-y-rightarrow-x-such-that

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to be precise: $f:A \to B$ is invertible if and only if it is bijective. If it is injective still you can invert $f$ but viewed as a mapping $f:A \to f(A)$. If you choose some $y \in B \setminus f(A)$ there is no $x \in A$ such that $f(x)=y$ therefore $f^{-1}(y)$ does not make sense

Comment: So in other words there are elements in $B$ that are impossible to reach from $A$ but every "reachable element" is still possible to invert uniquely? Or something like that?

Comment: Yes, that's true. For example in dealing with cyclometric function arcus sinus is defined as the inverse to sinus but viewed as a function $\sin:[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}] \to [-1,1]$. Sinus is not invertible viewed as a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and even as $[\pi/2,\pi/2] \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: So the answer is "Yes but the inverse is not necessarily a total function." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function

Comment: which is to say, it *is* invertible on its image. $f^{-1}: f(A) \longrightarrow A$.

Comment: cyclometric, thats a new word for me

Comment: @truebaran sorry I know that the answer is very old but I have a doubt...in your answer do you mean that if a function is injective is not necessarily invertible but if it is also surjective surely it is invertible?

Answer (score 13):

You should distinguish a left invertible, a right invertible  and an invertible function. 

Function $f:A\to B$ is **left** invertible if there exists a left inverse 
 i.e. $\exists g:B\to A: g(f(x))=x ~, \forall x\in A$

$f:A\to B$ is **right** invertible if there exists a right inverse, i.e. 
$\exists g:B\to A: f(g(y))=y ~, \forall y\in B$

(left/right invertibles can be stated in the reverse order depending on the style that composition of two functions are written)

$f(x)$ is an **injection** **iff** it is **left** invertible.
$f(x)$ is a **surjection**, **iff** it is **right** invertible.
$f(x)$ is **invertible**,  **iff** it is left and right invertible.

It is easy to prove that a function is invertible **iff** it has a left and a right inverse inverse (you may easily check that they are equal in this case).

Answer (score 9):

A function is invertible if and only if it is bijective (i.e. both injective and surjective). Injectivity is a necessary condition for invertibility but not sufficient.

Example:

Define 
$f: [1,2] \to [2,5]$ as $f(x) = 2x$. Clearly this function is injective.

Now if you try to find the inverse it would be $f^{-1}(y) = \frac{y}{2}$. But notice that for $y \in (4,5]$, $f^{-1}(y)$ does not exists as $f^{-1}(y): [2,5] \to [1,2]$. So the inverse is not a function.

Additional: This is not the case in maps. Injectivity is sufficient for invertibility (as the inverse need not be a function, just a map)

Comment: Could you explain about the "map" bit? I'm only aware of "map" as a synonym for "function".

Comment: Sorry, I should not use the term "map" here. I was thinking of the relations which are either one-to-one or many-to-one (not one-to-many). An element in the domain might not be mapped to any element in the range. In this case, injectivity is also sufficient for invertibility.

Answer (score 5):

If $f:A\to B$ is injective, $f$ is invertible if and only if $f(A)=B$. But $f:A\to f(A)$ is always invertible if $f:A\to B$ is injective.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness...

There is one variant of the idea of function that doesn't include a notion of codomain. e.g. with this notion, the function defined by $f(x) = x^2$ (where $x$ is a real variable) "remembers" that its domain is all reals and that its *image* (sometimes called its *range*) is all nonnegative reals, but doesn't care whether it's being construed as a mapping $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, a mapping $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, a mapping $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, or even something more exotic.

For *this specific* variation on the notion of function, it is true that every injective function is invertible.

I am under the impression that this notion of function was popular once but is no longer popular. However, it still sticks around somewhat due to inertia: e.g. people learned it that way so they taught it to others, related concepts have stuck around, that sort of thing.

For the more modern notion of function, it *does* "remember" its codomain, and we require the domain of its inverse to be the whole of the codomain, so an injective function is only invertible if it is also bijective.

Comment: When I was younger, a function had a domain definition, and was not necessarily defined on the full set. A function defined on all element was called an application. But maybe usage changed...

Comment: @Serge: Ah, that's interesting too. I know the modern word is "partial function", and "total function" is used for everywhere defined partial functions. But IMO, introductory courses in the US seem to be in a weird place where they want to talk about partial functions, but only ever define the notion of a total function.

Comment: My reference were from french courses in the 70's :-)