# When $|A|<|B|$ and the function $f: A \to B$ is injective, how do we define the inverse function $g$, with or without the extra elements in $B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need help to understand this elementary part in the set theory. We all have seen the diagram of an injective mapping where few elements of the range set has no pre-image in the domain.

[image: This picture taken from an answer posted in math.stackexchange]

My reasoning gets stuck when I think about how can I define the inverse function $g : B \to A$, where $A, B$ are sets with $|A|=n, |B|=n+2$ and there exists an injective mapping $f: A \to B$, such that each elements of $A$ gets mapped to exactly one element of the set $B$. Clearly set $B$ has extra two elements.

Since $f$ is injective, then $g$ has to be injective.

But my doubts are:-

$a$• when we construct the inverse function $g: B \to A$, then do we include those two un-mapped elements for mapping?

$b$• Is there any difference between these terms $\textrm{not mapping two elements of the domain to the range set}$ and $\textrm{two elements in the domain do not have images in the range set}$ ?

$c$• From the image it is clear that in case of injective mapping there can be elements in the range set who have no pre-image. But can we say that in case of inverse injective mapping some elements in domain (here set $B$) may have no image in the range set ( here set $A$)? If yes, doesn't it contradict the definition of a function?

Also my reasoning in case of constructing the inversion function $g$ in such cases is that the function should look like $g: B \setminus 2 \to A$, to keep the one-one format, but that is not same as $g : B \to A$.

Therefore I request to help me to clear my doubts here. Any response, answer, hints and suggestions are valuable and appreciated.

---

Thanks to everyone for suggesting links, notes and the answer.

Comment: In your example, the domain of $g$ is not the entire set $B$. The domain of a function is the set of all points for which a function is defined/has an image.

Comment: In particular, if $f$ is injective, then the inverse $f^{-1}$ has the domain $\operatorname{ran} f$ (and not $B$).

Comment: @DominikS so should the domain of $g$ be $B \setminus 2$ ?

Comment: See also the answer to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451001/is-every-injective-function-invertible).

Comment: So in case of an injective mapping $f: A \to B$ we may have $|A|<|B|$, but for the inverse injective function $g: B \setminus k \to A$, we have $|A| = |B \setminus k|$ .. Is it correct to say?

Comment: @TopoSet32: There are slight variations in how people define "inverse". If you are studying from a book (or from some lecture notes), would it be possible for you to include the definition that is used in your question? This would help avoid any confusion.

Comment: @Joe I am just using common inverse notion that is used in undergraduate level ( where range of a function becomes domain and domain becomes range regarding an inverse function).

I have seen that there are the notions of the right inverse and left inverse regarding the injective and surjective mapping, in some other posts in stackexchange. But myself being new in measure theory, is taking time to learn those concepts gradually.

Comment: @TopoSet32: Well, there is more than one notion of what inverse is, even at an undergraduate level. But, for the sake of definiteness, is the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Definitions) given on Wikipedia the one that you are familiar with? (By the way, I think you mean set theory, not measure theory.)

Comment: @Joe, My bad, I will be more careful in future before asking questions. Thank you very much for suggesting the wiki link. Also I mean my course measure theory which initially has started with set theory preliminaries (including this injective, surjective mapping definitions, cantor-bernstein-schroder theorem) etc.

Comment: @TopoSet32: Okay. Well, then according to the definition given on Wikipedia, if $f$ is injective, but is not surjective, then $f^{-1}$ *does not exist*. In fact, $f$ is invertible if and only if $f$ is bijective. This is because, by definition, the inverse of a map $f:A\to B$ must have a domain of $B$ and a codomain of $A$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149519/discussion-between-toposet32-and-joe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $f: A \to B$ must describe the *image* $f(a)$ in the codomain $B$ for each $a$ in the domain $A$. This image is unique. It's *the* image.

This is the forward direction: starting with elements of the domain and thinking about their image. But what about the backwards direction: starting with elements of the codomain and thinking about their preimage?

First of all, this preimage is best defined as a set because *it may not be unique* or *it may not exist*: for any $b \in B$, its *preimage* is
$$
f^{-1}(b) = \{ a \in A \mid f(a) = b \}. 
$$
Despite the suggestive notation, $f^{-1}$ is not necessarily a function in this context.

Here's where two important notions come in.

**1.** The function is **injective** (or *one-to-one*), if for each $b \in B$, its preimage has **at most** one element. In other words, its preimage is **unique**.

**2.** The function is **surjective** (or *onto*), if for each $b \in B$, its preimage has **at least** one element. In other words, its preimage **exists**.

In order to define an inverse function $g: B \to A$, we need for each $b \in B$ to determine $g(b) \in A$. This element of $A$ must exist and be unique. In other words, the original function $f$ must be surjective and injective. When we have both properties, we call the function **bijective** (or a *one-to-one correspondence*). In this situation, it's typical to write $f^{-1} = g$ for the inverse to $f$, satisfying
$$
f^{-1}(b) = a 
\quad\iff\quad 
f(a) = b.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborated clear answer. I don't have any doubt now. Thank you again. 

+1 for the answer.

Comment: It might be worth noting that even if $f$ is bijective, there is still a subtle difference between the value of the inverse map $f^{-1}$ at $b$ and the preimage of $b$ under $f$. The first thing is an element $a\in A$, whereas the second thing is the singleton $\{a\}$.

Comment: Yes, and technically, we speak of the preimage of a set as well, i.e. preimage takes sets to sets: for any $B' \subset B$, 
$$
f^{-1}(B') := \{ a \in A \mid f(a) \in B' \}.
$$
When $B' = \{b\}$ is a singleton, it's typical to abuse notation and write $f^{-1}(b)$ instead of the more correct $f^{-1}\bigl(\{b\}\bigr)$.